# What is the language generated by this grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

S → 0A | 1B | ɛ | 0

A → 0A | 0S | 1B

B → 1B | 1 | 0

I've tried to find some specific properties of some of the generated words, but I've failed.

Comment: Where did you find this? It doesn't seem to have any particular properties, what should we be looking for?

Comment: That's a regular grammar, in effect. Add a new start rule, get rid of the ε rule in the usual way, and then you have the NFA. Convert it to a regular expression and then see if you can simplify.

Comment: Professor said that it was possible to create a simpler grammar that generates the same language, so I was wondering how

Comment: @rici we haven't covered NFA, regex yet  in the class so is there a simpler way